# This is a generic design pattern regarding accessing model object value

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, model

In iOS, I have three controllers A,B,C. I have a model object and I am storing text box value in model property of an object and then I am storing model object in database where all this things happening in controller A. In controller C, I am trying to access that model object property, it shows me nil. I don't know why. Below is the example:

```
I have a model.m class like below
@implementation model:NSObject
@property(nonatomic)NSString *firstname;

A.m class
model m=[model alloc]init];
m.firstname=@"stackoverflow";
// and saving the "m" in PARSE framework which internally stores in database.

C.m class
model m =[model alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@",m.firstname);// shows null value
```

what is the right way to access it? Please help me in this case.

Comment: In C.m you are creating a brand-new object, so it's naturally going to have all properties reset to default values.  You need to fetch the object you saved in A.m.  As you don't show how you saved it, we can't tell you how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Single Instance